# How to generate schema repository for an existing oracle database

Tags: oracle, repository, ddl

Can someone please help me how can I generate/create schema repository to be maintained in bitbucket for an existing Oracle Database?
Currently, for example, if team needs to make a change in an existing package, they take the copy from Production DB. I want to maintain a repository of all the objects as DDLs in BitBucket. It should have the similar structure as we see in Developer tools like SQL developer/Toad etclike all Tables show together, all Views together, SPs together etc.
Is there any tool to achieve that?

Comment: sql developer can do that, you can use the Tools > Export feature to generate the ddl sql/plsql files for all the objects in your schema(s), and even put them in separate directories by type - see https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/unloading-an-oracle-schema-to-script-files-for-source-control/

Comment: You are essentially asking for a change control solution? I don't have experience with any real change control solutions for database objects, though I wouldn't doubt there are some out there. The closest thing I can think of to it would be a data modeling tool like ERWin. Personally, I keep table definitions in ERWin but everything else I simply keep the master copies of on my hard drive. A team could keep master copies on a shared drive or in any change control system protecting files. That could include DDL for tables, which you can get from many tools.

Comment: Another solution I use is to have a master database somewhere where all changes are made, and write a tool to compare every schema object in this master database with target databases, find differences and surgically sync them up so the targets match the master in every respect. In this manner, an entire complex schema could be upgraded across many databases with the single push of a button and a few minutes of processing time. But such a solution has to be custom written and is quite complex, something that would take weeks or months to write even by an experienced PL/SQL programmer.